# How do I choose the best URL to fetch?

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I'm looking for the best URL (say a local cache) at a set of URLs: ['https://1.2.3.4', 'https://httpbin.org/delay/3', 'https://httpbin.org/status/500'] and choose the best working one with a 5 second timeout. Else fallback to 'https://httpbin.org/status/200'. In this contrived example, 'https://httpbin.org/delay/3' should win!

```js
function fallback(response) {
  if (response.ok) {
    return response;
  }
  console.log("Trying fallback")
  return fetch("https://httpstat.us/200") // absolute fallback
}

var p = Promise.race([
    fetch('https://1.2.3.4'), // will fail
    fetch('https://httpbin.org/delay/3'), // should be the winner
    fetch('https://httpbin.org/status/500'), // will fail
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { // Competing with a timeout
      setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('request timeout')), 5000)
    })
  ])
  .then(fallback, fallback)
  .then(console.log)
```

The code I have has the problem whereby the [Promise race](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) ends when any returns. How can I best construct this so that 'https://httpbin.org/delay/3' will correctly win the race?

Comment: when you say "will fail", do you mean the promise rejects?

Comment: Nah the promise should always succeed unless the server is unreachable. What happens is that the server responds but the status is not 200, thus not a valid endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

```js
Promise.race([
  new Promise(resolve => {
    const ignoreError = () => {}
    // first to resolve with .ok gets to resolve the promise
    const resolveIfOk = res => res.ok && resolve(res)
    fetch('https://httpbin.org/delay/20').then(resolveIfOk, ignoreError)
    fetch('https://httpbin.org/delay/3').then(resolveIfOk, ignoreError)
    fetch('https://1.2.3.4').then(resolveIfOk, ignoreError)
    return;
  }),
  new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('timed out')), 4000)) // reject if timeout
]).then(function(value) {
  console.log("Success", value);
  return value
}, function(reason) {
  console.log("Going to use fallback", reason);
  return fetch('https://httpstat.us/200')
}).then(console.log)
```

The solution comes via https://twitter.com/secoif

Answer (score -1):

```js
function race(promises) {
  return Promise.race(Object.keys(promises).map((key) => {
      return promises[key]
    }))
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      if (!response.ok) {
        delete promises[response.url];
        return race(promises)
      } else if (Object.keys(promises).length == 0 || response.url == 'timeout') {
        console.log('returning default');
        return fetch("https://httpstat.us/200")
      }

      return response;
    })
}

race({
  'https://1.2.3.4': fetch('https://1.2.3.4'),
  'https://1.2.3.4': fetch('https://1.2.3.4'),
  'timeout': new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('request timeout')), 5000)
  })
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response)
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log('err:');
  console.log(err.message)
  return fetch("https://httpstat.us/200")
}).then(function(defaultFetch) {
  console.log('timed out requesting failed urls, getting default:');
  console.log(defaultFetch);
});
```

Comment: rather test for !response.ok than specific error like 500. Also could you insert a snippet so it can be run? :)

Comment: Inserted snippet

Comment: this is close, but if all fail, the fallback isn't tried

Comment: Edited original snippet.

Comment: I don't think the key,value test structure is needed. Object.keys look ugly to me! What about showing how the https://httpbin.org/delay/3 wins??